# Is it possible to append `-o` options to `ps -Af` to display e.g. UID/GID as part of the output?

Tags: debian, process, ps

I find `ps -f` very useful, since it provides a robust default set of output columns.

However, I also often want to display the UID/GID etc as part of the output. Is it possible to append output columns using e.g. `ps -o` to the set of `ps -f` output columns?

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:~$ ps -Af -o gid,uid | grep sleep
error: conflicting format options

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

Furthermore, is there any `grep` built into `ps`, so that I don't miss the column headers, when grepping for the command?

`man ps`:

```
-o format
              User-defined format.  format is a single argument in the form of a blank-separated or comma-separated list, which
              offers a way to specify individual output columns.  The recognized keywords are described in the STANDARD FORMAT
              SPECIFIERS section below.  Headers may be renamed (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o comm=Command) as desired.  If all
              column headers are empty (ps -o pid= -o comm=) then the header line will not be output.  Column width will increase as
              needed for wide headers; this may be used to widen up columns such as WCHAN (ps -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o
              comm).  Explicit width control (ps opid,wchan:42,cmd) is offered too.  The behavior of ps -o pid=X,comm=Y varies with
              personality; output may be one column named "X,comm=Y" or two columns named "X" and "Y".  Use multiple -o options when
              in doubt.  Use the PS_FORMAT environment variable to specify a default as desired; DefSysV and DefBSD are macros that
              may be used to choose the default UNIX or BSD columns.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-O` option to add columns to a default selection, but it doesn’t match `-f`: `ps -O uid,gid` shows pid, uid, gid, state, tty, time and command. (The manpage mentions a “state”-less variant, which I assume is supposed to correspond to ”System V” v. “BSD” mode, but [the column definitions for `-O`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/cc032cbd99345f4bcc1f3e99eed7a716cd313419/ps/output.c#L1763) don’t support this.)

If you want a specific set of columns you need to specify them completely; with `procps-ng`’s `ps`, the equivalent of `-f` ([`-o uid_hack,pid,ppid,c,stime,tname,time,cmd`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/cc032cbd99345f4bcc1f3e99eed7a716cd313419/ps/output.c#L1813)), with uid and gid added after the `uid_hack` column, is

```
$ ps -o uid_hack,uid,gid,pid,ppid,c,stime,tname,time,cmd
```

`procps-ng` also supports “macros”; its manpage mentions “DefBSD” and “DefSysV”, but [many others are defined](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/cc032cbd99345f4bcc1f3e99eed7a716cd313419/ps/output.c#L1759), including `Std_f` which is the setting used for `-f`:

```
$ ps -o Std_f,uid,gid
```

`ps` can filter its output using a number of criteria; to search for `sleep`, use `-C`:

```
$ ps -C sleep -o uid_hack,uid,gid,pid,ppid,c,stime,tname,time,cmd
```

Comment: In the BSD `ps`s, `-O` is documented as inserting all of the named columns after the `PID` column in whatever set of columns has been chosen.  The idea is that `-o` is for completely overriding the selected (default/full/long/jobs/user/vm) format, and `-O` is for augmenting it.

Comment: @JdeBP right, but with `procps-ng` `ps`, `-O` can’t be combined with another format selection, so `-f -O uid,gid` doesn’t work :-(.

Comment: Yes, it isn't getting it right again.  (It's not even [the old BSD behaviour from years ago](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/bin/ps/ps.c?rev=1.61&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).)  But I'm in part pointing out that that's why one gets the columns that one does.  It's not recognizing "full" format, but it _is_ inserting after the `PID` column, just in one of the "default" formats instead.

Comment: @JdeBP yes, I got that ;-). But in `procps-ng`, `-O` extends its own, separate column selection, which doesn’t match any of the presets AFAICT.

Comment: It does.  It's one of the "default" formats.  Note the plural.  This is hinted at in the manual.  It picks different "default" formats (and different "full", "long", "user", and "jobs" formats) according to which purported "personality" it thinks that it is.  It actually has at least _7_ different "default" formats, including _two_ Debian ones (one "[fictional](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/ps/output.c#L1773)").

Comment: @JdeBP no, it’s not. There’s no default format matching `pid,state,tname,time,cmd`. [`-O` uses `pid`, the user-specified format](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/ps/sortformat.c#L106) then a [specific trailer](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/ps/output.c#L1764).

Comment: @StephenKitt - why does `-O` choose between to output formats: `-o pid,format,state,tname,time,command` or `-o pid,format,tname,time,cmd`? Also, should it be understood that `procps-ng’ include `uid` and `gid` in `-f`'s output?

Comment: @Shuzheng the docs claim that, but the code doesn’t support that claim... It goes back to the weird “BSD” v. “System V” distinction in `procps-ng`. Re. `-f`, see my update; it doesn’t include `uid,gid`, but it does include the username (`uid_hack`).

Comment: Just to be sure, I use `procps-ng` by default on Debian 9, right?

Comment: @Shuzheng yes, version 3.3.12 of `procps-ng`. Debian switched in 2011.

Comment: Hah!  You're right.  _Even more_ idiosyncratic and oddball than its own manual implies ("The use of BSD-style options will...").  What an utter mess.